# Adding user defined menu to Enterprise Architect element

Tags: c#, events, add-in, enterprise, enterprise-architect

I am working on Enterprise Architect c# add-ins and I need to display a user-defined context Menu when any element is right-clicked in diagram workspace or Project Browser instead of the default Menu.

There are context Item events available for contextItemClicked,contextItemDoubleClicked etc. Is there any add-in event available for the right-click of an element.

Kindly Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that [EA_OnContextItemChanged](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/ea_oncontextitemchanged.html) will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[EA_GetmenuItems](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/eaadd-insea_getmenuitems.html) has some parameters to control the context menu depending on the selected element, and you can still `Repository.GetContextObject()` or `Repository.GetContextItemType()` to refine it even more.